# How can multiple people in my organization access multiple client Google Analytics accounts?

Tags: google, google-analytics

I work at a web development and marketing agency. We need to access multiple client GA accounts.

Currently we handle this by having a google@domain.com account, which people at our organization log into when they need to access client Analytics accounts. This brings about a few issues:

1. It's not the most secure approach, we're sharing a password amongst multiple people.
2. We have a forced 2fa policy, which means we have a point of failure should we need to login quickly and the person set up on 2fa isn't available (eg the person whose phone is used is on holiday).
3. When someone leaves the business this all needs resetting.

It would make sense to have some kind of organization that the client can add to Analytics rather than having to add each member individually. We use Google Workspace for everything so I sort of expected this to be obviously available, but it isn't anywhere I can find.

What's the correct approach to this?

FWIW I have contacted Google via Live Chat about this but they don't seem to understand the problem, and have recommended each client each individual team member, which brings about even more problems.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience working with agencies, granting permissions to an entire organisation isn't possible.

A common approach is to create a [User Group](https://support.google.com/marketingplatform/answer/9013855?sjid=1899695474457851714-AP#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) which simplifies the process of aligning users and permissions. However, it's worth noting that each user within the group will still need to be added individually.